# TreeView Autoscroll while dragging

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Winforms TreeView, I want to scroll up/down when the user drag and item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you implement drag and drop in a treeview control, you need to support some type of auto-scroll functionality. For example, when you drag an item from a visible tree node, and the destination tree node is outside of the current view of the treeview, the control should automatically scroll up or down depending on the direction of the mouse.

The Windows Forms Treeview control does not include built-in functionality to accomplish this. However, it is fairly easy to implement this yourself.

Step 1: Get your treeview drag and drop code working

Make sure your treeview drag and drop code works correctly without autoscrolling. See the topics in this folder for more information on how to implement drag and drop in a treeview.

Step 2: Add a definition for the SendMessage function

In order to tell the treeview to scroll up or down, you need to call the Windows API SendMessage() function. To do this, add the following code the top of your class:

```
// Make sure you have the correct using clause to see DllImport:
// using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage (IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, 
        int lParam);
```

Step 3: Hook into the DragScroll Event

In the DragScroll event, determine where the mouse cursor is in relation to the top and bottom of the treeview control. Then call SendMessage to scroll as apporpriate.

```
// Implement an "autoscroll" routine for drag
//  and drop. If the drag cursor moves to the bottom
//  or top of the treeview, call the Windows API
//  SendMessage function to scroll up or down automatically.
private void DragScroll (
    object sender,
    DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Set a constant to define the autoscroll region
    const Single scrollRegion = 20;

    // See where the cursor is
    Point pt =  TreeView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

    // See if we need to scroll up or down
    if ((pt.Y + scrollRegion) > TreeView1.Height)
    {
        // Call the API to scroll down
        SendMessage(TreeView1.Handle, (int)277, (int)1, 0);
    }
    else if (pt.Y < (TreeView1.Top + scrollRegion))
    {
        // Call thje API to scroll up
        SendMessage(TreeView1.Handle, (int)277, (int)0, 0);
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip21.asp).

Comment: Maybe change `(TreeView1.Top + scrollRegion)` to `(scrollRegion)`. In my opinion you do not need the top value. First I tried with adding TreeView1.Top (the treeview is at the bottom of my form) and the scroll process startet at the middle of the treeview. So I removed TreeView1.Top and the scroll startet at the top of my tree view.

Comment: @shaahin, could you post the actual winapi macro definitions?

I know that 277 is WM_VSCROLL, but I can't make sense of the 1 and the 0 from the header files.

Comment: Thanks! I hooked it to the DragOver event, because there is no such event as DragScroll

Answer (score 22):

Pretty much the same as the above, but without that 'top' bug and a bit simpler to use in bigger projects.

Add this class to your project:

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static void Scroll(this Control control)
    {
        var pt = control.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        if ((pt.Y + 20) > control.Height)
        {
            // scroll down
            SendMessage(control.Handle, 277, (IntPtr) 1, (IntPtr) 0);
        }
        else if (pt.Y < 20)
        {
            // scroll up
            SendMessage(control.Handle, 277, (IntPtr) 0, (IntPtr) 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply subscribe to the DragOver event of your treeview (or any other control/custom control you want scrolling enabled while drag/dropping) and call the Scroll() method.

```
    private void treeView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView.Scroll();
    }
```

Comment: @Vedran this is great! but is there a way to make the TV scroll a bit slower? Mine seems to be going a little fast... ?